# How to prevent a context class using the state design pattern from having too many responsibilities?

Tags: design-patterns, state-pattern

I am making use of the state design pattern for a project of mine where I have a Car class which is the context class and it can have 3 states - neutral, drive and park. In each of those states, the car can execute different actions such as in Neutral, you can play a movie in the car, in Drive you can do something else and in Parked as well.

Now, I can see the benefits of the state design pattern, not using too many if statements and keeping logic separate for each state and making it easily extensible code but after some thinking I am not sure how to prevent the Context class from having way too many responsibilities. At the moment I have just a few actions but in the future I might want to add like 5-6 actions per different state and then my Context class will be full, in addition to keeping track of the speed of the car, fuel etc.

First of all, is that a problem and second, if yes how to prevent that?

I tried researching online but could not see any articles on the Context class having too many responsibilities which led me to thinking that maybe this is normal but still I am not completely sure.

Here are places I went to to search for information regarding this pattern:

RefactoringGuru:
https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state/java/example

DoFactory:
https://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern

Baeldung:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-state-design-pattern

I went to a few more places but the information more or less is the same. They go give general examples but in none of them I can see clearly defined what is inside the Context. I see that it is passed as an parameter to the specific state objects and they use it to call private fields or a method but that does not answer my question.

Comment: It is a good point, I will update my question. Thank you for upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that you have missed one of the point of the State pattern. From the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern):

> Implementing state-specific behavior directly within a class is inflexible because it commits the class to a particular behavior and makes it impossible to add a new state or change the behavior of an existing state later, independently from the class, without changing the class. In this, the pattern describes two solutions:
>
> - Define separate (state) objects that encapsulate state-specific behavior for each state. That is, define an interface (state) for performing state-specific behavior, and define classes that implement the interface for each state.
> - A class delegates state-specific behavior to its current state object instead of implementing state-specific behavior directly.

So the idea is to encapsulate the state behaviour outside the context class and move it to concrete state implementations.

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

The context class will delegate actions (requests) to the concrete states.

Comment: So that would mean that if I want to do action X in state Neutral, I would do that action only inside this state? At the moment I do use context.PlayMusic() inside the Neutral state but the PlayMusic method is declared in the context. I don't execute it in the context.

Comment: Also, in Context I have private fields regarding speed, fuel etc. If I put them in a specifc state then I do not have access to them in the other states. Thus at the moment they are in the Context and I just do context.GetSpeed() in the specific state.

Comment: @AngelHadzhiev _"So that would mean that if I want to do action X in state Neutral, I would do that action only inside this state"_ - exactly. You should create some generic contract like `class ActionDescriptor { ActionType, ActionData}`  (`ActionData` is optional. For example it can contain song to be played) for example and pass it to the context which will pass it to the concrete state.

Comment: @AngelHadzhiev _"Also, in Context I have private fields regarding speed, fuel etc. If I put them in a specifc state then I do not have access to them in the other states"_ - those should remain in the context. That is the idea of the  context - to store such data.

Comment: Well, then I think that I do not break this design principle because this is what I do, I do actions in the states and I store fields in the context. My worry was that at some point I might keep way too many fields and this might make my class Context too big.

Comment: @AngelHadzhiev I would argue that stuff like `context.PlayMusic()` means that your kind of break it. Adding a new action to the state will require context change even if there is no need to add new data to it. Context has responsibility to store data and pass the request to the current state.

Comment: Could you provide me with some examples of state design pattern applied the way you think is correct so I can look into them?

Comment: Also, would it not be the case that PlayMusic is the request method from the example you shared? It is requesting for music to be played in Neutral state?

Comment: @AngelHadzhiev the thing here is that `handle` is a single method which is shared between all states. You will have a bunch of methods.

Comment: Yes. Is it possible that some methods are not executed in some states and only in other states?

Comment: @AngelHadzhiev yes. In this case you throw an error or something like this. You can also expose method `getSupportedActions` on the state.